# Does the deduction theorem hold in Q?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory, hilbert-calculus

The proof of the deduction theorem (for a system including Hilbert Calculus) that I am familiar with uses *modus ponens* to prove the result one way, and mathematical induction the other way.

Robinson's Arithmetic, $Q$, is defined as $PA$ without the induction scheme. Does this entail that the deduction theorem does not hold in $Q$? Or is there another proof?

Comment: The Deduction Th holds in every FO theory, i.e. in every theory based on FO axioms plus modus ponens. The form of the DT is : if $\Gamma \cup \{ \alpha \} \vdash \beta$, then $\Gamma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$. $\Gamma$ can be exactly the colelction of non-logical axioms that defines $\mathsf Q$.

Comment: The induction used in the proof of DT is performed in the meta-theory and does not require the presence or not of unduction **in** the list of axioms of the theory $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, deduction theorem holds in *Robinson arithmetic* $Q$. Let us prove it, relying on the fact that deduction theorem holds for the *Hilbert calculus* $H$.

Suppose that $\vdash_Q A \to B$, i.e. that $A \to B$ is provable in the system $Q$. System $Q$ is nothing but *Hilbert calculus* $H$ (its axioms and its inference rules) plus the axioms $Q_1, \dots, Q_7$ of Robinson arithmetic. Therefore, $\vdash_Q A \to B$, means that $Q_1, \dots, Q_7 \vdash_H A \to B$, i.e. $A \to B$ is provable in the system $H$ under the assumptions $Q_1, \dots, Q_7$. By the deduction theorem for the system $H$, we have that $Q_1, \dots, Q_7, A \vdash_H B$, i.e. $B$ is provable in the system $H$ under the assumptions $Q_1, \dots, Q_7, A$. But this exactly means that $A \vdash_Q B$, i.e. $B$ is provable in the system $Q$ under the assumption $A$.

Therefore, we proved that if $\vdash_Q A \to B$ then $A \vdash_Q B$, i.e. the deduction theorem holds for the system $Q$ (Robinson arithmetic).

Answer (score 2):

It's really a bit of a weird question to ask if the deduction theorem holds for $Q$ ... $Q$ is a theory about numbers; its axioms express elementary arithmetical truths.  Whereas the Deduction theorem is about *logic*, so that has really nothing to do with the axioms of $Q$.

Now, it *does* make sense to say that the Deduction Theorem holds for $H$, because $H$ is a theory for logic: using its axioms, together with Modus Ponens, you can derive logical truths.

But again, to ask whether the deduction theorem holds for $Q$ is misguided. Indeed, typically you are using a *proof system* in addition to the axioms of $Q$, in order to actually to do some inferencing, and prove further arithmetical truths. And you could then ask whether the Deduction Theorem holds for that *proof system*.... though typically in the context of discussing $Q$, it is implicitly assumed that we are using a sounds and complete proof system, meaning that the Deduction Theorem does hold for that proof system.